# How to use Distinct On with COALESCE

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct-on

I'm trying to build a query which sums up a column for all rows with unique IDs (interested only in the latest entry for a given ID). The thing is the IDs are coming from one of 2 columns so I'm using COALESCE. This is what I roughly want:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(ct.amount), 0)
FROM (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT ON (COALESCE(NULLIF(pt.originalID, 0), pt.ID)) id,  -- use originalID otherwise ID
    pt.amount
  FROM prettyTable AS pt
  WHERE ...
  ORDER BY pt.creation_time DESC
) AS ct
...
```

So I want the most recently created amount for each unique id where the id comes from either `originalID` or if that's 0 then simply `ID`.

Note: I've tried adding the `creation_time` to the select clause but that doesn't work. I've also tried matching the ORDER BY with the SELECT but I can't make that work either...

Example Rows:

```
originalID, ID, creation_time, amount, ...
 0        ,  1, 2004-10-19   , 10 -- add to sum

 0        ,  2, 2004-10-20   , 10 -- coalesced id=2; ignore 
 2        ,  3, 2004-10-21   , 20 -- coalesced id=2; ignore
 2        ,  4, 2004-10-22   , 30 -- coalesced id=2; add to sum

 0        ,  5, 2004-10-23   , 10 -- coalesced id=5; add to sum
 5        ,  6, 2004-10-19   , 60 -- coalesced id=5; ignored
```

The result for the above should be the sum of the 1st, 4rd and 5th rows = `10 + 30 + 10 = 50`

Comment: can you show samples from your tables and the output you need? @Martin

Comment: @lemon yes, I've updated the question with an example, obfuscated the non important columns and simplified the timestamp format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ORDER BY` clause requires the column you applied `DISTINCT ON` on in its definition, hence your problem may be solved like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(ct.amount), 0)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON 
          (COALESCE(NULLIF(pt.originalID, 0), pt.ID)) id,     
          pt.amount
      FROM prettyTable AS pt
      ORDER BY (COALESCE(NULLIF(pt.originalID, 0), pt.ID)),
               pt.creation_time DESC
) AS ct
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fkgm1aRnuiL99UPSBrrFBH/3).

Comment: Thanks! do you mind giving the subquery solution as well?  

Comment: Also, do you think you can come up with a solution using a coalesce/distinct on?

Comment: Adopting `COALESCE` would make this solution more complex as you need to do two operations (first convert zeroes to `NULL`, then using the `COALESCE`), whereas the `CASE` statement uses a more direct approach. If you want I can provide you a snippet, but I wouldn't recommend it in any case. @Martin

Comment: yep, we're on psql that's why I was hoping I can make use of that

Comment: That was my misread on the tags. Updated accordingly for PostgreSQL DMBS. @Martin

Comment: You are golden! thank you so much for following up